# Displaying a plot of Matplotlib subplots in an Array

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm using the pandas plotting toolkit to plot a scatter matrix of some data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix

data = pd.read_csv('results_true.csv',header=False)
data = data.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1)

ax = scatter_matrix(data,diagonal='hist',alpha=0.5,
                    hist_kwds={'bins':np.sqrt(999),'alpha':0.9,'histtype':'step'},
                   grid=True,range_padding=0.4,
                   figsize=(15,15),marker='o',s=0.3)

plt.clf()

new_ax = np.empty(ax.shape,dtype=object)

for i in xrange(0,ax.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(0,ax.shape[1]):
        if j >= i:
            new_ax[i][j] = ax[i][j]
```

The output in terminal for new_ax is

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x9c4f74c>,
        <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x9f256cc>,
        <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x9fa9b8c>,
        <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0xa04758c>,
        ...,
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
        <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0xed9c30c>]], 
dtype=object)
```

I'm doing this so I can plot just half of the scatter matrix instead of the redundant top diagonal. Is there a way I can just plot new_ax in its form?

Comment: It might be easier to use [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#plotting-pairwise-relationships-with-pairgrid-and-pairplot) -- look about halfway down the page for the example with `map_upper`, `map_lower`.

Comment: That's a good resource but it'd be nice to have something quick for this, for now.